# Why the distribution of M(t) is the same as X(t)?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $ B(t)(t\geq 0) $ be the standard Brownian motion and $ M(t)=\max_{0\leq s\leq t}{B(s)} $. If we define $ X(t)=M(t)-B(t) $ as a new stochastic process, how can I show that $ X(t) $ has the same distribution as $ B(t) $? I have tried to use the property of Brownian motion to calculate $ P(M(t)>x,B(t)>y) $, but I cannot figure out this probability when $ x>y $. Can anyone give some hint or thoughts about it?

Comment: $X(t)$ has the same distribution as $M(t)$ or $|B(t)|$ rather than $B(t)$ (note that $X(t) \geqslant 0$, while $B(t)$ can be negative). This is a standard result known as the [reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)) and it follows as a corollary from the strong Markov property (with certain caveats!).

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Surely if $X(t)$ has the same distribution as $|B(t)|$, then it doesn't have the same distribution as $M(t)$, because $M(t)$ is nondecreasing while $|B(t)|$ can decrease?

Comment: @WillSawin: The problem lies in the meaning of the word "distribution", I suppose. For a fixed $t$, the random variables $X(t)$, $|B(t)|$ and $M(t)$ have the same distribution. (That said, of course these are different random variables: no two of them are equal with probability one). Additionally, $X(t)$ and $|B(t)|$ have equal law as stochastic processes: both are reflected Brownian motions, but of course law of $M(t)$ is different.